# Angularjs: How to capture the text in <td> tag and use it inside my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, semantic-ui

I need to capture the id and title value of the row for which the edit button was pressed.

Here is how my ng-repeat is structured:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="post in posts">
      <td>
       <div class="ui singlenum checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="unique-1">
        <label for="unique-1">{{post.id}}</label>
       </div>
      </td>
      <td>{{post.title}}</td>
      <td>{{post.posted_on}}</td>
      <td>{{post.is_moderated}}</td>
      <td>
            <div id="editbtn" ng-click="showCustom()" class="circular ui icon button">
              <i class="edit icon"></i>
            </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

And this is the part of my controller code where I need to access the particular `{{post.id}}` and `{{post.title}}` value.

```
app.controller('SampleController', ['$scope', 'ModalService', function($scope, ModalService) {

$scope.showCustom = function() {
 ModalService.showModal({
      templateUrl: "complex/complex.html",
      controller: "ComplexController",
      inputs: {
        id: // This is where I need to specify the id for which the edit button was pressed.
        title: // This is where I need to specify the title for which the edit button was pressed.
      }
    }).then(function(modal) {
      modal.element.modal();
      modal.close.then(function(result) {
        $scope.complexResult  = "Name: " + result.name + ", age: " + result.age;
      });
    });

  };
```

I need to access the `post.id` which is in a `label` and `post.title` which is wrapped in a `<td>` element. `ng-model` does not work for these type of elements so I can't use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `post` parameter to your function like `showCustom(post)`.

```
<div id="editbtn" ng-click="showCustom(post)" class="circular ui icon button">
  <i class="edit icon"></i>
</div>
```

Which you can use it in controller.

```
$scope.showCustom = function(post) {
    var postId = post.id; //Get id
    var title = post.title; //Get Title
    //Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Ahh man!! I knew it would be something that simple. Just couldn't figure out what it was. Thanks for the prompt response though. Problem solved.